# Errors In Unity 3d Server Script C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

public string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public int Port = "25001";

    void OnGUI()
    {

        if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
        {

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Join Existing Server"))
            {

            Network.Connect(Ip,Port);   

            }



            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Create New Server"))
            {

            Network.InitializeServer(10,Port);
                //First Number Above next to port in perenthisies is number of allowed clients / 1x Server (# of players allowed to join game.)

            }

            else 
            {

            if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)  
                {


                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Client");
                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
                    {

                        Network.Disconnect(250);


                    }


                }
                if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server)
                {

                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Server");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Connections: " + Network.connections.Length);

                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
                    {

                        Network.Disconnect(250);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is my code however it is generating the following errors that I for some reason can not find a way to rectify:

1. Can not implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Any help regarding this would be appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 1):

While declaring the port declare it as

```
public int port = 25001;
```

This is because, we use "" only for declaring strings and string cannot be converted to integer implicitly. Hope this helps you. Anything else just post it here.

Comment: Mention the errors and we shall try to help you out. also tell us the line where you can see more errors..

Comment: 1. ip does not exist in current context
2. the best overloaded match for unityengine.network.connect(string,int') has some invalid arguments.

3. #1 cannot convert 'object' expression to string

AND 

unityengine.Initializeserver is obselete?

Comment: The lines are as follows:

1. 19,29
2. 19,21
3. 19,21
4. 28,21

Comment: Replace public string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public int Port = "25001"; with public static string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public static int Port = "25001";

Comment: sorry my mistake it should be public static string IP = "192.168.0.8"; public static int Port = 25001;